# Splitting line by percentage length in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, splitting, qgis-2.18

I'm using QGIS 2.18.9.

How do I split a line by percentage?

In the case of a line, split it by percentage length.

My use-case is more for roads where I would like to split a segment (by %). So, I can use the line feature to determine the length and then create a buffer as shown.

[image]

Comment: Splitting a polygon by a percentage should be a different question to splitting a line by a percentage.  I think you should focus this one on the former, and if the other is not already asked and answered on this site, then ask that separately.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happened to the other **10%**? ;)

Comment: you got my red handed @Joseph. :) its a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may run this simple code from the Python Console:

```py
percentage = 0.6 # Set the percentage

layer = iface.activeLayer() # Load it as you want

# Create the output layer
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()
outLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs='+ crs, 'catchments_new' , 'memory')
prov = outLayer.dataProvider()
fields = layer.pendingFields() # Fields from the input layer
prov.addAttributes(fields) # Add input layer fields to the outLayer
outLayer.updateFields()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    line_geom = feat.geometry()
    leng = line_geom.length()
    print leng
    dist = (percentage * leng)
    center_pt = dist * 0.5
    pt = line_geom.interpolate(center_pt)
    buffered_geom = pt.buffer(center_pt, 2000) # set the second parameter sufficiently enough for avoiding creating odd behaviors
    itx = line_geom.intersection(buffered_geom)
    diff = line_geom.difference(buffered_geom)

    outGeom_1 = QgsFeature()
    outGeom_1.setAttributes(attrs)
    outGeom_1.setGeometry(buffered_geom)
    prov.addFeatures([outGeom_1])

    outGeom_2 = QgsFeature()
    outGeom_2.setAttributes(attrs)
    outGeom_2.setGeometry(diff)
    prov.addFeatures([outGeom_2])

# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
```

It will create a new line memory layer that stores each original line feature as two splitted new features depending on the percentage you have set.